# How do vampires in "Twilight" handle human periods?

Tags: vampire, twilight

If vampires go crazy with the smell of bloody, how did the Cullens tolerate Bella when she had her period? A small cut caused Jasper to attack.

Comment: Re: Theodore Sturgeon's "Some of Your Blood"

Comment: I felt that my answer to this was pretty comprehensive. Is there any else you'd like to be addressed before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but menstrual "blood" isn't actually the same kind of tissue as what circulates in your arteries and veins, is it? I was under the impression it was the dissolved remains of the inner lining of the uterus that builds up in parallel with ovulation, and is then shed unless a fertilized ovum implants within the layer.

Answer (score 23):

The author, Stephanie Meyer covered this in an interview for the [Twilight Lexicon](http://www.twilightlexicon.com/2006/03/11/personal-correspondance-2/). According to her, menstrual blood does not have the same potency as "fresh" blood and Edward is (thusly) able to control himself better.

> **Meyer:** *Edward can’t be around Bella when she’s bleeding without being in
> intense temptation–to the point of pain.  A few drops would only make
> it worse.  Like a few drops of water when you’ve been wandering in the
> desert for days…  You’d totally suck down the whole gallon of Evian.*
>
> *Several girls wanted to know **if Edward would have a more difficult
> time being around Bella when she’s having her period**.  Answer: **Yes, a
> little bit, but he would never say anything about it – much too much of
> a gentleman.  And Bella would be way to embarrassed to ask.  (It’s not
> the same as a cut, though.  It’s sort of "dead" blood, if you get my
> meaning).***

Comment: For me, Meyer just gave a sloppy answer for that. _"Dead" blood?_ C'mon...

Comment: Period Blood isn't dead, it's full of rich cells that cover the womb to help the baby grow. They don't change when they're discarded, they are just discarded because there is no baby to use them... It is actually very much alive and could be re-use that why a lot of animals re-absorb their periods.